# Python PyQt Qlabel Resize

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel

I'm having trouble here trying to set my Qlabel size to be bigger. Here is my code. I'm not sure what to do. I have tried lots...

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(UICreator, self).__init__(parent)
    self.Creator = QPushButton("YouTube", self)
    self.Creator.resize(100, 40)
    self.Creator.move(25, 50)
    self.CreatorB2 = QPushButton("Twitter", self)
    self.CreatorB2.resize(100, 40)
    self.CreatorB2.move(275, 50)
    self.CreatorL = QLabel("Created By:", self)
    self.CreatorL.resize(100, 100)
    self.CreatorL.move(20, 300)
```

Comment: Just a question on the side: are you sure you want fixed geometry for all your widgets? Unless you have a strict display size writing scalable UI is the preferable way to go. Using a layout will take care of the resizing (though you can set the size policy of every widget to ensure a specific way of handling resize events for each of these).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "bigger"? And what, specifically, have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using PyQt4 then make sure you imported:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
```

then add this line to set size of the label:

```
self.CreatorL = QLabel("Created By:", self)
self.CreatorL.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 80, 100, 100)) #(x, y, width, height)
```

Comment: No sorry for not saying but im using pyqt4

Comment: Just replace PyQt5 by PyQt4.

Comment: @Achilles. In what way is your answer any different to what the OP already posted? Why do you think it would produce a different outcome?

Comment: @ekhumoro Are you sure? Please specify.

Comment: @Achilles. Do you understand what `move`, `resize`, and `setGeometry` do?

Comment: Yes.OP asked for "Qlabel size to be bigger" and this does the job perfectly.

Comment: @Achilles. The OPs code resizes the label to 100x100. How does your code do anything different to that? If you wanted to "make it bigger", why didn't you just suggest `resize(500, 500)`?

Comment: @Achilles. If you try it, you'll see that the two approaches are exactly equivalent. They both resize the label to 100x100. But anyway, no matter how big you make the label, it won't make it *look* any bigger. A `QLabel` has no frame, and resizing it does not alter the text it contains.

Comment: @ekhumoro hey I was wondering how would I alter the text size or font, etc? I could not find the solution anywhere

Comment: @DuttaA `label.setFont(myfont)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro but does it change the size too?

Comment: @DuttaA. Why not just try it? Or read the [qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html) to see what can be done with a font object?

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks I found it, its just the documentations are a bit  weird..its in c++

Answer (score 3):

`setGeometry` works perfectly unless you're using a layout where the dimensions need to be something specific, for which I use `setFixedSize` This should help guarantee that your widget doesn't get unintentionally compressed or expanded due to a grid layout or something like that.

So it'd be something like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

my_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
my_label.setText('My Label')
my_label.setFixedSize(50, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

To Add to Achilles comment since I foukd this useful...

the values actually go (x, y, width, height)

if you want to do a relative change then something like this will work:

```
    self.CreatorL = QLabel("Created By:", self)
    self.CreatorL.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.CreatorL.x()+50, self.CreatorL.y(), self.CreatorL.width(), self.CreatorL.height()))
```

where this example will move the label 50 pixels to the right. Self.CreatorL can be replaced by the name of the label object.